# How do you interpret the 'fixed effects' for bivariate smooths in the 'lme' part of a gamm model in R?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

When fitting a 'gamm' model in the R package `mgcv`, and using a smooth of two variables, the lme part of the model reports two fixed effects : 'Fx1' and 'Fx2' with coefficients and standard errors.

How should one interpret those coefficients? I realize according to the ?gamm docs that the procedure fits straight lines with the 'wiggles' added as random effects. Are these the coefficients for the linear part of these smooths?

example:

```
library(mgcv)
dat <- gamSim(1,n=200,scale=2)
b <- gamm(y~s(x0, x1),data=dat)
summary(b)
```

produces:

```
...

Fixed effects: y.0 ~ X - 1 
                 Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
X(Intercept)  7.318201 0.2380636 197 30.740527  0.0000
Xs(x0,x1)Fx1 -1.823521 0.2319144 197 -7.862906  0.0000
Xs(x0,x1)Fx2  0.483693 0.2455482 197  1.969848  0.0503
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; more correctly, they are the unpenalised parts of the basis. If you had a different derivative-based penalty, on say the integrated 3rd (or 1st) derivative of the smooth you would have more (fewer) unpenalised functions in the basis (respectively).

The coefficients are weights for the unpenalised functions:

- `X(Intercept)` this is the model intercept or constant term
- `Xs(x0,x1)Fx1` is the slope of the first linear basis function, in `x0`
- `Xs(x0,x1)Fx2` is the slope of the second linear basis function, in `x1`